# Global Scriptable Object

Tags: unity-game-engine, singleton, scriptable-object

Suppose I have this ScriptableObject to represent a list of cards:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "CardList", menuName = "Inventory/List", order = 1)]
public class CardList : ScriptableObject {
    public string[] cardName;
    public Sprite[] cardSprite;
}
```

Then I create the ScriptableObject and fill it with all my cards information.

Is there a way to modify this code so that any script have access to it statically? For example, is it possible to give `CardList` a singleton behaviour?

I don't want to create another class, it would be easy to create  a `ScriptableObjectManager` that could reference `CardList`. I'd rather call something like `CardList.instance.cardName[i]` directly.

Comment: Nevermind my last comment, I missed what you are getting at. [This blog post](https://baraujo.net/unity3d-making-singletons-from-scriptableobjects-automatically/) might be more helpful here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely, you can create it as singleton so for this.
Suppose that we have Unity Project that has file hierarchy like

```
UnityProject
- Assets (directory)
    Scripts
        SampleScriptableObject.cs   
- Resources (directory)
    SampleScriptableObject.asset
- Project
- ..etc
```

in "SampleScriptableObject" class will be like

```
public class SampleScriptableObject<T> : ScriptableObject where T : ScriptableObject  
{
    private static T _instance;
    public T GetInstance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = Resources.Load(typeof(T).Name) as T;
        }
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

you can use scriptable object as singleton as you want.

Comment: How do you use this? I've implemented it in my project but can't find a way to access it.

Comment: var spts = GamepadSprites<GamepadSprites>.GetInstance(); ?? This works but looks weird.